# How to layout iOS with little content?

Tags: gui-design, ios, iphone, ipad, dynamic-ui

I am new to iOS development and was wondering how to layout the UI when I don't have much content?

Below are the two extreme sizes of iOS device, iPhone 4s and iPad Air. The 4s screen looks OK but the Air looks ridiculous. Any suggestions on how to lay it out?

**iPhone 4s**                                                             **iPad Air**
[image]
[image]

Comment: You could set buttons as percentages of screen estate. Like for example make the bottom 15% of the screen some color and write with a big enough font "continue"

Comment: I agree with @downrep_nation this is the beauty of responsive design, making the interface work for every device. You could also look into media queries if you prefer that over percentages. Also random opinion thrown in, I would lean away from the grayscale design, it makes the text hard to read, the buttons look disabled, and when the phone dims it will be very hard to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a comment about precentages.

you could attempt to do something similar to this:
[image: showcase]

do NOT make this design. it has many flaws and should not be replicated on a real app, its just to show how big UI elements that take up a fixed range on the screen can look good

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the commenter who suggested making the buttons a percentage of the screen width, rather than a fixed size.

You could also put the app in the middle of the screen and have some whitespace around it. Quite a few iOS apps do that.

I wouldn't centre the layout, as it makes it harder for the eye to follow.